# Using @WebParam(header = true) in CXF web service

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm trying to write a web service that has only one massage param and the rest are header params.
My web service looks like this:

```
    @BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
    @MTOM
    @WebService(targetNamespace = WS_NAMESPACE + "/FileSvc")
    @Service
    public interface FileSvc
    {
        void uploadFile(@WebParam(name = "dataHandler") @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")DataHandler dataHandler,
                    @WebParam(header = true, name = "fileName") String fileName,
                    @WebParam(header = true, name = "fileSize") long fileSize);
    }
```

The services factory is defined like this:

```
    <bean id="fileSvcProxyFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="serviceClass" value="com....FileSvc"/>
            <property name="address" value="http://.../FileSvc"/>
            <property name="bus" ref="client_bus"/>
            <property name="dataBinding" ref="globalJAXBDataBinding" />
    </bean>
```

When I try testing this service -from a java client I get this error when I try loading the service:

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Message
>   part {http://.../FileSvc}fileName of Message
>   {http://.../FileSvc}uploadFile cannot be processed. This can be
>   caused by the use of JAX-WS-specific types without the JAX-WS service
>   factory bean.

Can anyone explain to me how this webParam works?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the globalJAXBDataBinding thing and seeing if that helps.  Alternatively, add @RequestWrapper and @ResponseWrapper annotations to the interface methods to point at appropriate wrapper types.    Not 100% sure that will work, but worth a shot.

If it still doesn't work, a small full testcase would be appreciated.

Comment: I removed the globalJAXBDataBinding (its a wrapper we wrote for CXFs JAXBDataBinding) and it looks like it works. Thanks

Comment: Can you explane to me why this should work. I really need to use the globalJAXBDataBinding because we have more the 5,000 classes and about 20 web services. So we have to use a global binding. I don't see how using a wrapper helps (I have to have the whole massage body only for the DataHandler or the C# client can't use the service), it makes no deference. Do I have more options or will it help you to see the whole picture?